# How can I get information from another app

Tags: android

I am new to Andorid development.

I am trying to write a small application for Android device.
One thing that I want is to get information from another installed application.

**EDIT:**

I want my application to do A and B, and I found a application that already does part A,so what I am trying to do is to extend the functionality of the existing application

is there a generic way to retrieve information from another app?

Comment: Nope, no way to do what you edited in a generic way, if the other app isn't designed to do just that (assumed you don't have root). It'd be a nightmare if it was possible...

Answer (score 1):

@dprogramz gave a really good answer but to build on it you may want to take a look at `startActivityForResult` if you're looking to get a photo or use input from some external activity.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) is here

Answer (score 0):

What information?

If it is shared information that lives in a shared directory then it shouldn't be any problem at all.

If it is protected information you will have to give your app access to these files.

If it is "real-time" information you will have to invoke an API. take a look at the application class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: I want my application to do A and B, and I found a application that already does part A,so what I am trying to do is to extend the functionality of the existing application. I would take a look at the reference, Thanks.

Comment: @user844541 what is practical really depends on a lot on the size and nature of the information - and please edit that into your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a possibility to extend a app X with a feature A. You can add a new feature B to the app and make it more scalable and realiable,
only if-
Project is Open-Source:
You can contribute to the app via github and push changes.
If the owner likes it, you can be hire.
OR
Download the existing the project, make changes and upload it.